# CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The number of elements in the collections do not match

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing

So in my test class I have these:

```
private static readonly List<Address> budapestStreet1Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address(47.29, 19.04, "HU", "Budapest", "1111", "street1", "2"),
            new Address(47.30, 19.06, "HU", "budapest", "1111", "street1", "3"),
            new Address(47.31, 19.05, "HU", "BUDAPEST", "1111", "street1", "4"),
        };

        private static readonly List<Address> budapestStreet2Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address(47.31, 19.05, "HU", "BUDAPEST", "1111", "street2", "5"),
        };

        private static readonly List<Address> budapestSTREET1Addresses = new List<Address>()
        {
            new Address(47.31, 19.05, "HU", "BUDAPEST", "1111", "STREET1", "6")
        };

[TestMethod]
        public void F4AGetAddressesOfStreetInCity()
        {
            using (var dbConn = TestDbHelper.CreateConnection())
            {
                var dbContext = TestDbHelper.CreateDbContext(dbConn);
                addTestAddresses(dbContext);

                var service = new AddressService(dbContext);

                var foundBudapestStreet1Addresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("budapest", "street1");
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(budapestStreet1Addresses, foundBudapestStreet1Addresses);

                foundBudapestStreet1Addresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("BudaPest", "street1");
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(budapestStreet1Addresses, foundBudapestStreet1Addresses);

                var foundBudapestStreet2Addresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("Budapest", "street2");
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(budapestStreet2Addresses, foundBudapestStreet2Addresses);

                var foundBudapestSTREET1Addresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("Budapest", "STREET1");
                CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(budapestSTREET1Addresses, foundBudapestSTREET1Addresses);

                var foundBudapestStreeT1Addresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("budapest", "streeT1");
                Assert.AreEqual(0, foundBudapestStreeT1Addresses.Count);

                var foundLondonAddresses = service.GetAddressesOfStreetInCity("London", "street1");
                Assert.AreEqual(0, foundLondonAddresses.Count);
            }
        }
```

And this is the actual method:

```
public List<Address> GetAddressesOfStreetInCity(string city, string street)
        {
            return dbContext.Addresses.Where(x => EF.Functions.Like(x.City, city) && EF.Functions.Like(x.Street, street)).ToList();
        }
```

But when I run the test, I get the following message:

CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent failed. The number of elements in the collections do not match.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There are some other addresses in the database probably from previous test runs.

Put a breakpoint on the line with `CollectionAssert` and examine both collections, this will shed the light on the mystery.